# Problem when fetching data from API, and filling this data into a list, flutter

Tags: flutter

When I fetch data from the API and fill in this data in a list, I get the following error:

**I/flutter ( 4822): my e ::::; type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'BannersModel'**

I tried a lot but to no avail:

Code attached below:

```
class HomeModel {
  late bool? status;
  late HomeDataModel? data;

  HomeModel.fromJeson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json["status"];
    data = HomeDataModel.fromJeson(json["data"]);
  }
}

class HomeDataModel {
  late List<BannersModel> bannerss = [];
  HomeDataModel.fromJeson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json["banners"].forEach((e) {
      bannerss.add(e);
    });
  }
}

class BannersModel {
  late int? id;
  late String? image;

  BannersModel.fromJeson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"];
    image = json["image"];
  }
}
```

**I think this code is wrong**
**This is a function to fetch data and fill it in the list**

```
void getDataProdc() {
DioHelper.getData(path: "home", token: tokennn).then((value) {
  homeProdcModel = HomeModel.fromJeson(value.data);
}).catchError((e) {
  print("my e ::::; ${e.toString()}");
});}
```

---

**If this is excluded:**
*homeProdcModel = HomeModel.fromJeson(value.data);*

**And we wrote this:**
*print(value.data);*
**Like the code below:**

```
void getDataProdc() {
DioHelper.getData(path: "home", token: tokennn).then((value) {
  //homeProdcModel = HomeModel.fromJeson(value.data);
  print(value.data);
}).catchError((e) {
  print("my e ::::; ${e.toString()}");
});}
```

**I will get a result that it will print all the data, meaning that the call function is correct, but there is a problem in filling in this data in the custom list in the model**

---

**This is what was printed using a print code only**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDQaa.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of your API response? The `value.data` mainly.

Comment: Can you show here what is printed on the console for `value.data`?
Dummy values will work, I need the structure and data type of the response.

Comment: I attached a picture did you see it?

Comment: If you can add it in the editor like you added the code snippet instead of an image then I'll be able to test my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `HomeDataModel.fromJeson` factory constructor.

```dart
late List<BannersModel> bannerss = [];// <-- This list is of BannersModel data type
  
HomeDataModel.fromJeson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  json["banners"].forEach((e) {

    bannerss.add(e);  // <-- You have to use BannersModel.fromJson function

  });
}
```

Try the below code.

> Note: I have not tested it

```dart
 HomeDataModel.fromJeson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    (json["banners"] as List<dynamic>).forEach((e) {
      bannerss.add( BannersModel.fromJeson(e as Map<String, dynamic>));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Not related to the question. `late List<BannersModel> bannerss = [];` The above line can be improved. You are defining the variable with `[]` so it's not null and we don't need to use `late`.
Refer to [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables).